# NotGeoreferencedWarning while doing .compute() on dask xarray

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray, rasterio

1. I am working in Planetary Computer and managed to get my data into Xarray using Stackstac. I can view it and it says its an Xarray DataArray.
2. I can do operations on it like .mean() and .groupby().
3. But when I do **data.plot()**, I first see this Warning:
   **NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix will be returned.**
4. This is followed by a super long stack trace, at the end of which I see:
   **ValueError: Can't read closed raster file**. ( I am guessing this is happening because the file is getting close after some time by the stackstac rio_reader())
5. When I do **data.compute()** and **data.values** to see the data, I get the same error!
6. This is the code to get the signed items into xarray:
   data = stackstac.stack(items, assets=['no2'], epsg=4326, resolution=0.01, bounds_latlon=bbox)

Attaching a screenshot of the data[image]

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The raw data itself in this collection is not georeferenced. So GDAL/rasterio/stackstac cannot understand it. This is why I get the NotGeoreferenced warning.
This is the GitHub thread where this was answered.
[GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/PlanetaryComputer/discussions/223)